# How can I read and write OData calls in a secure way? (not vulnerable to CSRF for example?)

Tags: javascript, httpwebrequest, xss, odata, csrf

What is the most secure way to open a [OData](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2011/02/10/short-datajs-walk-through.aspx) read/GET endpoint without risks to CSRF attacks like [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx) one?

I haven't looked at the source, but how does the [MSFT ODATA library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948527/new-odata-javascript-library-from-msft-compared-to-jquery) compare to jQuery in this regard:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData was designed to prevent the JSON-hijacking attack described in the link by returning only objects as JSON results, which makes the payload an invalid JavaScript program and as such won't be executed by the browser.

This is really independent of whether you use datajs or jQuery. I haven't looked at the exact result you get from jQuery, but I know datajs will "unwrap" the results so you get a more natural-looking result, without any artificial top-level objects.

In particular, the WCF Data Services implementation for .NET doesn't support JSONP out of the box, although there are a couple of popular simple solutions to add it. At that point, though, you've basically opted into allowing the data to be seen from other domains, so this is something that shouldn't be done for user-sensitive data.